# Chrome/Chromium: 20-30 seconds delay before a download will start

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, downloads

Before on Ubuntu 17.04 and now after upgrading on 17.10: Current Chrome and Chromium makes a 20-30 seconds break between clicking a download-file and starting the download.

It has no matter on which website and it's the same problem if i choose the direct-download-link or the save-under-button in the context menu. The save-under-dialog also takes 20-30 seconds to pop up.

What i tried:

- deleting cookies and cache
- deleting the complete browser history
- deleting download-history

On Firefox the downloads are starting directly, but i don't like to switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is working for me. In Chrome or Chromium open extended settings and scroll down to the bottom and reset Chrome/Chromium completely. Your website-history, favs and your password-settings will not be touched.

But reactivate extensions like add-blocker and so on carefully, because in Chromium i had one of them in my list, which ist starting the above problem again.